# How to show that the subring $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is "maximum" in $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let's define $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}= \left\{ \frac ab\in \mathbb Q\mid a,b\in \mathbb Z,p\nmid b \right\}$. We can show that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is a subring of $\mathbb Q$. How can we show that the only subring in $\mathbb Q$ that contains $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ are $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ and $\mathbb Q$? This question come from an exercice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ZZp}{\Bbb Z_{(p)}}$Let $R$ be a subring of $\Bbb Q$ strictly containing $\ZZp$. It suffices to show that $R$ contains $1/p$. Because $R$ is not equal to $\ZZp$, it contains some element outside $\ZZp$. Express that element in lowest terms as $a/b$, and convince yourself that $p \mid b$. Therefore, $p \nmid a$. Write $b = pc$, and note that $c/a \in \ZZp$. Thus, $a/b \cdot c/a = 1/p \in R$.

Comment: Ok, but why should we show that R contains $1/p$?

Comment: One way to think about it is "which elements are invertible". Every element is invertible iff every prime is invertible. In $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$, every prime except $p$ is invertible. In an overring where $p$ is invertible, then every prime is invertible, so you have to contain $\Bbb Q$. Another, more concrete, way of thinking about it is: any element of $\Bbb Q$ can be written as $a/b \cdot 1/p^n$, where $p \nmid b$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $\frac ab = \prod\limits_j p_j^{\alpha_j}$, where $p_j$ are primes, $\alpha_j \in \mathbb Z, p_0 = p$, and consider the function $$\pi\colon \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Z,\quad \prod\limits_j p_j^{\alpha_j} \mapsto \alpha_0.$$ This is well defined, since $\mathbb Z$ is an UFD.

Note that $\pi(\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}) \subseteq \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$.

Take the ring you get from $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ by including in it a number $x$, such that $\pi(x) \leq -1$.

Then $p^{\pi(x)}$ is in this ring, and since $p^{-\pi(x) - 1 } \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, we know that $p^{-\pi(x) - 1 }p^{\pi(x)} = \frac 1p$ is also in this ring.

Implying, that this ring is indeed $\mathbb Q$.